# Public-key / asymmetric cryptography on ESP32/ESP8266

Tags: cryptography, esp8266, public-key-encryption, esp32, encryption-asymmetric

I am currently trying to secure the transmission of IoT devices for my ESP32 and ESP8266 based projects. As there are functions for ESP-TLS and RSA available and also HTTPS support, there should be something like this available. Unfortunately I could not find anything in ESP-IDF an also no usage/code examples. Has anyone been working with this? Are there examples available?
PS: I am not looking for an Arduino library and I have already checked the AES ECB/CBC buy I am explicitly looking for a pub/sub functionality using the internal function of the ESP-IDF.

Comment: this commit https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/commit/9ec363a25d8c68c18e99027b60f099531cd5885b suggests it's recently been made private, for "reasons"